macos Sequoia - how to fix "Killed: 9" when attempting to run Jtool2?
I'm experiencing what appears to be a gatekeeper error in macos Sequoia.
I am trying to run the jtool2 command line utility. I've downloaded and unpacked jtool, When run in the terminal all that happens is that I see "Killed: 9" in response:
$ ./jtool2 --help
Killed: 9
$

In previous macos versions I've also experienced similar GateKeeper issues with JTool but I've been able to add it as an exception either by using spctl or through the Security and Privacy control panel.
Neither of these approaches work now. So how do I get jtool2 to run under Sequoia?
